# How to check a string for valid email addresses and separators

Tags: php, regex

I am using a `textarea` to allow the user to enter multiple email addresses, separated by comma. Furthermore there will very likely be space characters and linebreaks.

How can I check/assure in PHP, that the string from the `textarea` only contains valid email adresses (syntactically valid, no DNS check or so), space characters or linebreaks? Space characters and line breaks may not exist within an email address (which would anyway break the first restriction of address validity).

Comment: Use `$emails = array_map('trim', explode(';', $emailList))` and literally any of the 100,000,000 email checkers that have been made in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  function checkTextArea($textarea){
    $textarea = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", " "), "", $textarea);
    $textarea = explode(";", $textarea);
    foreach($textarea as $res){
      if(!filter_var($res, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ 
         return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Something like this. You could replace the line breaks/spaces with comma ; if user forget to separate with come and uses space.
If you do that, there can be multiple ; following each others: if ($res) is empty do not check for mail validity, just ignore

Answer (score 0):

**RegEx Validation**

```
// get your email list from your textbox
$emailList = "test@abc.com, myname@abc.com, php@account.com, test.com";

$ArrayList = explode(", ", $emailList);
$regex = '/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/'; 
foreach($ArrayList as $address)
{
    if (preg_match($regex, $address))
    {
        print $address." Is valid Email<br>";
    }
    else
    {
        print $address." Is Invalid Email<br>";
    }
}
```